# Graphql subscriptions inside a useEffect hook doesn't access latest state

Tags: reactjs, apollo, react-apollo, apollo-client

I'm building a basic Slack clone. So I have a "Room", which has multiple "Channels". A user subscribes to all messages in a Room, but we only add them to the current message list if the new message is part of the user's current Channel

```
const [currentChannel, setCurrentChannel] = useState(null);

const doSomething = (thing) => {
  console.log(thing, currentChannel)
}

useEffect(() => {
  // ... Here I have a call which will grab some data and set the currentChannel

  Service.joinRoom(roomId).subscribe({
    next: (x) => {
      doSomething(x)
    },
    error: (err: any) => { console.log("error: ", err) }
  })
}, [])
```

I'm only showing some of the code here to illustrate my issue. The subscription gets created before `currentChannel` gets updated, which is fine, because we want to listen to everything, but then conditionally render based on `currentChannel`.

The issue I'm having, is that even though `currentChannel` gets set correctly, because it was null when the `next:` function was defined in the `useEffect` hook, `doSomething` will always log that `currentChannel` is null. I know it's getting set correctly because I'm displaying it on my screen in the render. So why does `doSomething` get scoped in a way that `currentChannel` is null? How can I get it to call a new function each time that accesses the freshest state of `currentChannel` each time the `next` function is called? I tried it with both `useState`, as well as storing/retrieving it from redux, nothing is working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually it is related to all async actions involving javascript closures: your `subscribe` refers to initial `doSomething`(it's recreated on each render) that refers to initial `currentChannel` value. Article with good examples for reference: https://dmitripavlutin.com/react-hooks-stale-closures/

What can we do? I see at least 2 moves here: quick-n-dirty and fundamental.

1. We can utilize that `useState` returns exact the same(referentially same) setter function each time and it allows us to use functional version:

```
const doSomething = (thing) => {
  setCurrentChannel(currentChannelFromFunctionalSetter => {
    console.log(thing, currentChannelFromFunctionalSetter);
    return currentChannelFromFunctionalSetter;
  }
}
```

2. Fundamental approach is to utilize `useRef` and put most recent `doSomething` there:

```
const latestDoSomething = useRef(null);
...
const doSomething = (thing) => { // nothing changed here
  console.log(thing, currentChannel)
}
latestDoSomething.current = doSomething; // happens on each render

useEffect(() => {
  Service.joinRoom(roomId).subscribe({
    next: (x) => {
      // we are using latest version with closure on most recent data
      latestDoSomething.current(x) 
    },
```

Comment: This is super helpful. Thank you so much.